# Does computer on or connected to mains deplete CMOS battery?

Tags: bios, battery, cmos

Computers have a CMOS battery to operate the real-time clock and retain BIOS settings. There are two ways in which the CMOS battery can fail: either it is past its shelf life or alternatively its capacity is depleted.

Now, if I keep a computer continuously on, do the RTC and BIOS still deplete the CMOS battery?

What if I keep the computer off but continuously connected to mains so that standby power is still offered to the motherboard? Is the CMOS battery in this case depleted?

If the answer to both of these questions is "no", I guess none of my computers require CMOS battery replacement until the battery is past its shelf life which takes probably around 10 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no universal answer for this: I personally have seen a Mainboard drain its Battery within two years of being powered on continuously (Intel Server Board), and I have seen batteries work for 10+ years on old servers, that are never powered off.

So it seems that the design of the MB heavily influences the CMOS battery lifetime.

Comment: Yes, what you have told is happened in my environment also.